# C# UnZip file with special characters

Tags: c#, character-encoding, zip

I'm using this code:

```
FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(archiveFilenameIn);
zf = new ZipFile(fs);
```

When I extract the zip file it breaks the special character of the pdf that is inside the zip:

[image]

Comment: ZIP should work with any characters.  There are different versions of ZIP specification and optional  features.  So often using ZIP with one tool will give issues when unzip with a different tool.  Also there are issues when you create a zip and then add additional files.  You may not be able to unzip usually due to optional requirements.

Comment: Please do not post images of code or errors, please paste them in as text